# C# Mvc3 asp.net Building a dynamic connection string

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, appharbor

I need to build a dynamic connection string as shown in [this tutorial](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1354-connection-string-auto-replacement-for-entity-framework-projects):

However this code is very above my skill level. Can any help guid me through this(be very specific, please)?

The tutorial states that we need to create a partial class, but where should does this class be placed?

My .edmx file is named DBModel.edmx

my .tt file is name TraxzDBContext.tt

The connection string need to be similar to the one that follows:

```
<add name="TraxzDBEntities"
 connectionString="metadata=res://*/;
       provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
       provider connection string='Data Source=d5d3955e-1183-4e10-8892-9f9d005af0a8.sqlserver.sequelizer.com;
       User ID=1; 
       Password=1;
       Initial Catalog=dbd5d3955e11834e1088929f9d005af0a8;
       MultipleActiveResultSets=True'"
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Or if there is a better method of creating a dynamic string in the same fashion that is created in the tutorial, let me know.

Thanks to anyone who solves this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a partial class in any place in the same assembly where your `DBModel.edmx` file is. Just make sure that you use the same namespace.

Comment: ok this helps, however, the tutorial says to change the following in the .tt file the following way:                                       public <#=code.Escape(entity)#>() : base(GetConnectionString(), "<#=entity.Name#>")                                                      The issue is I am not sure what to place in "<#=entity.Name#>""      Also does the name of the partial class matter?

Comment: Leave "<#=entity.Name#>" alone, just add `GetConnectionString(), ` in front.

Comment: I feel like we are almost there! But I am reciveing the error GetConnectionString() does not exist in current context. I made a class under my models folder which looks like this: public partial class Model1Container
    {
        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
         }

Comment: As I already said, make sure that the namespace is the same (and obviously the name of the class is the same) as for the other partial class. You should be able to see other properties/methods in VS members dropdown.

Comment: Yes the namespace for both is namespace Traxz.Models; I am not sure what you mean by " (and obviously the name of the class is the same) as for the other partial class"; Does which class has to have the same name as the partial class?

Comment: DbContext - you want to create a partial class for your DBContext class (generated from your .tt file). Do you know what a partial class is?

Comment: No I am not familiar with partial class- can you give an example of this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5108/discussion-between-jakub-konecki-and-aziz)